# In my jquery select2 search option isnt appearing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

I am using Jquery select2() inside a modal. I have included the link int layout file where the page got layout from

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

My code for modal is here:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <select class="js-example-basic-single button3" name="state">
                    @foreach($brands??array() as $brand)
                        <option>
                            <div role="listitem" class="quicklinks__item quicklinks__item--nav w-dyn-item" style="width: 300px;">
                                <a id="Nav-Quicklink" href="/vehicles?brand={{ $brand->slug }}"
                                    class="quicklinks__link w-inline-block"><img
                                            src="{{url($brand->photo??'')}}"
                                            alt="Bugatti" class="quicklinks__logo" />
                                    <div class="quicklinks__details">
                                        <div class="quicklinks__title">{{ $brand->name }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
```

in this file I added the jquery inside script tag:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
    });
</script>
```

But the search box isnt appearing. Only select list is appearing. [image]

What went wrong? How can I get the search box? TIA.
The file is [here](https://github.com/yasirarafat28/Royaltyexoticcars/blob/master/resources/views/frontView/index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's look like select2 was not applied to your code. Did you import jQuery?

Add

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

above

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes. its imported in the layout file above select2.min.js

Comment: you can see it here https://github.com/yasirarafat28/Royaltyexoticcars/blob/master/resources/views/layouts/front.blade.php

Comment: Did you check console output? Maybe there is some errors and guide us.

Comment: Console refering a Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function. But I included the link in the layout file

Comment: Can you try to move select2 js file right before </body> tag but above select2 init

Comment: select2 init is not inside body. As it is inside modal.

Answer (score 0):

Remove This library

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

and replace with this library

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet">
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js' defer></script>
```

If still doesnt work try replace **ID** instead of **class** when declare select2

**Dropdown**

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <select class="js-example-basic-single button3" name="state" id="test">
                    @foreach($brands??array() as $brand)
                        <option>
                            <div role="listitem" class="quicklinks__item quicklinks__item--nav w-dyn-item" style="width: 300px;">
                                <a id="Nav-Quicklink" href="/vehicles?brand={{ $brand->slug }}"
                                    class="quicklinks__link w-inline-block"><img
                                            src="{{url($brand->photo??'')}}"
                                            alt="Bugatti" class="quicklinks__logo" />
                                    <div class="quicklinks__details">
                                        <div class="quicklinks__title">{{ $brand->name }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#test").select2();   
});
```

**PS: Make sure the script is inside form(Before  close tag) !!!**

Comment: You can check it here https://github.com/yasirarafat28/Royaltyexoticcars/blob/master/resources/views/frontView/index.blade.php

Comment: Its not a big file

Comment: @NabidAnzum have u try replace class with id?

Comment: Yes I did. @Steven94

Comment: The console is refering to Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

Comment: @NabidAnzum try add this <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js" defer></script>

Comment: add defer at the end of src

Comment: @NabidAnzum look's like there's a conflict between jquery libraries that's why it wont render the select2 library